# Optimal number of partitions in a grouped PairRDD in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, partitioning

I have two pair RDDs with the structure RDD[String, Int], called rdd1 and rdd2.

Each of these RDDs is groupped by its key, and I want to execute a function over its values (so I will use mapValues method).
**Does the method "GroupByKey" creates a new partition for each key or have I to specify this manually using "partitionBy"?**

I understand that the partitions of a RDD won't change if I don't perform operations that change the key, so if I perform a mapValues operation on each RDD or if I perform a join operation between the previous two RDDs, the partitions of the resulting RDD won't change. **Is it true?**

Here we have a code example. Notice that "function" is not defined because it is not important here.

```
val lvl1rdd=rdd1.groupByKey()
val lvl2rdd=rdd2.groupByKey()
val lvl1_lvl2=lvl1rdd.join(lvl2rdd)
val finalrdd=lvl1_lvl2.mapValues(value => function(value))
```

If I join the previous RDDs and I execute a function over the values of the resulting RDD (mapValues), all the work is being done in a single worker instead of distributing the different tasks over the different workers nodes of the cluster. I mean, the desired behaviour should be to execute, in parallel, the function passed as a parameter to the mapValues method in so many nodes as the cluster allows us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the best numberOfPartitions for coalesce?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40865326/6910411)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Avoid **groupByKey** operations as they act as bottleneck for network I/O and execution  performance.
Prefer **reduceByKey** Operation in this case as the data shuffle is comparatively less than groupByKey and we can witness the difference much better if it is a larger Dataset.

```
val lvl1rdd = rdd1.reduceByKey(x => function(x)) 
val lvl1rdd = rdd2.reduceByKey(x => function(x))
//perform the Join Operation on these resultant RDD's
```

Application of function on RDD's seperately and joining them is far better than joining RDD's and applying a function using groupByKey()

This will also ensure the tasks get distributed among different executors and execute in parallel

[Refer this link](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)

**2)** The underlying partitioning technique is **Hash partitioner**. If we assume that our data is located in **n** number of partitions initially then **groupByKey** Operation will follow Hash mechanism.

```
partition = key.hashCode() % numPartitions
```

This will create fixed number of partitions which can be more than intial number when you use the **groupByKey** Operation.we can also customize the partitions to be made. For example

```
val result_rdd = rdd1.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(2))
```

This will create 2 partitions and in this way we can set the number of partitions.
For deciding the **optimal number of partitions** refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40866286/7449292