# Interaction of spark configurations with input structure

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, cluster-computing, warc

Spark has many configurable options. Here, I would like to know what the optimal configuration is under certain constraints.

I have seen many of these post and do not think the approach of neglecting the structure of the data can yield in a satisfactory solution.

### **Cluster Config**

We will set the already established `--executor-cores 5`, because of the previous research done. Let us set another constraint such that the `--executor-memory 60 Gb` is the threshold maximum. This may be expressed as `--executor-memory` = min(60 Gb,`EM`).

We fix the number of nodes in our cluster to `N_0`, which implicitly regulates the `--num-executors` (equal to `N_0 * average num-cores on node / 5`).

### **Data Config**

We are presented with data in the form of `FN_0`-many text files of equal size `FS` (approx. 1 Gb) loaded into an `RDD`. This `RDD` has initially a partiton number `PN` equal to `FN_0`. Loading all the files into the RDD results in records `RN = RDD.count()`.

**Question**

I would like to find a qualitative expression or optimal solution for the `--executor-memory`, `--num-executors` and partition number `PN` for an Input -> Map -> Filter -> Action job, in terms of `N_0,FN_0,FS,RN`. What is their inter-dependency?

My assumption is that the partition number would be ideal at `RN` (approx. 100.000), so that every record has its own task, but this shuffle would scale astronomically. I would also appreciate any thoughts in regards to the relationship between he product `FN_0 * FS` and `--executor-memory`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the best numberOfPartitions for coalesce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40865326/how-to-calculate-the-best-numberofpartitions-for-coalesce)

Comment: There was this "Don't try to use fixed number of partitions based on the number of executors or cores. First understand your data and code, then adjust configuration to reflect your understanding". Which is a indicator for the partitioning being independent of the `executor`, but I do not see how it explains the dependency regrading the data-format/size.